# How to add conditionally add a new key value pair to a json using jq?

Tags: json, bash, key, jq, logical-operators

I have a json file formatted as below

```
[
    {
        "foo" : "fooValue",
        "bar" : "barValue"
    },
    {
        "foo" : null,
        "bar" : null
    }
]
```

I want to add a new key value pair `baz` to this json using jq based on the existence of values for keys foo and bar. If foo and bar are both not null, then `baz` should be the string "true". If either foo or bar are null or both are null, then `baz` should be string "false". What is the best way to accomplish this using jq? I understand how to append a key value pair to a json, but I am not sure how to do this process conditionally. Thank you

Comment: What should happen if one is true, and the other one is false?

Comment: Then baz should be null, updated question accordingly

Comment: Please include commas between the items to make it a valid JSON input. Also note for the mixed case that `null` (as in your comment) and `false` (as in your updated question) are not the same value.

Comment: Should baz be the _string_ `"false"` or the _boolean value_ `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the boolean [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) [operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#and%2Cor%2Cnot) `and` based on `.foo`'s and `.bar`'s (in)equality to `null`, [assign](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Plainassignment%3A%3D) the result to a new key `.baz`, and [`map`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#map%28f%29%2Cmap_values%28f%29) the input using this filter.

```bash
map(.baz = .foo != null and .bar != null)
```

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "fooValue",
    "bar": "barValue",
    "baz": true
  },
  {
    "foo": null,
    "bar": null,
    "baz": false
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nAYZIB-bmtJ)

---

If the new values should indeed be strings, simply [interpolate](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation%3A%5C%28exp%29) the computed booleans:

```bash
map(.baz = "\(.foo != null and .bar != null)")
```

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "fooValue",
    "bar": "barValue",
    "baz": "true"
  },
  {
    "foo": null,
    "bar": null,
    "baz": "false"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/55FYRy9PRsL)